# How to implement cookie handling on Android using OkHttp?

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp

Using OkHttp by Square https://github.com/square/okhttp, how can I:

1. Retrieve a cookie returned from the server
2. Store the cookie for upcoming requests
3. Use the stored cookie in subsequent requests
4. Update the cookie returned by the subsequent request

Ideally the cookie would be stored, resent and updated automatically with every request.

Answer (score 75):

For OkHttp3, a simple accept-all, non-persistent `CookieJar` implementation can be as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
        private final HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
            cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
            return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
        }
    })
    .build();
```

Or if you prefer to use `java.net.CookieManager`, include `okhttp-urlconnection` in your project, which contains `JavaNetCookieJar`, a wrapper class that delegates to `java.net.CookieHandler`:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0"
}
```

---

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
    .build();
```

Comment: So automatically saves and nothing I have to do? After restarting works?

Comment: No the example is for non-persistent cookie jar. For persistent solution, you can implement your own, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25462286/836540, and wrap it with JavaNetCookieJar.

Comment: Btw, url is a 'FULL URL' to server and it will only send cookies when making the request to exact same URL. You might want to replace `cookieStore.put(url, cookies);` to `cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);`  For loadForRequest, `coookieStore.get(url.host());`. AND Replace `HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>>` to `HashMap<String, ...>`

Comment: @hidro how do i construct Cookies?

Comment: Using `Cookie.Builder`? https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Cookie.java#L451

Comment: Adding codes below helped me. Thanks!

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
    .build();

Comment: FYI : In the near Future, they plan to remove the okhttp-urlconnection module.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Using just the HttpUrl limits the cookie to just that url - and isn't really particular helpful. It should just be the domain name as the key - and then it works as intended.

Comment: This is wrong. `saveFromResponse` **replaces** the list instead of **merging** them. It means that setting any cookie erases all cookies set in previous requests.

Comment: I agree with @Agent_L. This replaces all cookies each time new cookies arrive. This means if you login, receive an auth cookie in response, then make another request that returns a different cookie in the response, the auth cookie will get overwritten and you will no longer be logged in.

Comment: @Agent_L and how do I merge the cookies ?

Comment: @MaximToyberman You'd want something that looks like this                
                   `private final HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

                    @Override
                    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                        if(cookieStore.containsKey(url.host())) {
                            cookieStore.get(url.host()).addAll(cookies);
                        } else {
                            cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
                        }
                    }`

Comment: Still not able to get the response. There is some session issue showing in server.But since it runs in web and iOS as well as i have no other option just to check my code.

Comment: Can't figure out why the session did't work with `CookieJar` implementation. `CookieManager` works like a charm.

Answer (score 36):

### For OkHttp 3 <sup>(or maybe newer)</sup>

See [hidro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746219/8740349)

### For OkHttp 2.x <sup>(or maybe older)</sup>

You can pass a CookieHandler to your OkHttpClient instance.  You can use the CookieManager implementation from java.net or you could implement your own if you want.  Choose the policy that works best for your needs.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);
```

OkHttp will save cookies received from Responses into the CookieHandler and read from it when sending requests. It will do so for matching request/response URIs.

Comment: Important to note: CookieManager isn't persistent. Next time you launch your app, the cookie jar will be empty.

Comment: @JesseWilson, so how to make it persistent?

Comment: Persistent cookies aren't yet implementated. If you need em, you need to make your own CookieStore.

Comment: @JesseWilson You are right. Here is a library that helps to persist CoockieJar https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar

Answer (score 9):

I needed to share the default Cookie Jar (CookieManager.getInstance()) so this seemed to work ok for me.

```
return new CookieJar() {

        @Override
        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookieManager.setCookie(url.toString(), cookie.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            List<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
            if (cookieManager.getCookie(url.toString()) != null) {
                String[] splitCookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url.toString()).split("[,;]");
                for (int i=0; i<splitCookies.length; i++) {
                    cookies.add(Cookie.parse(url, splitCookies[i].trim()));
                }
            }
            return cookies;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks It works really fine. Great job. Simple Solution, Thanks !!

Comment: hii @hmac your this approach works for me. 

Can you guide me how to clear the cookie when user logout?

Comment: I solved the issue of clear cookies. Here is the link might helped someone https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505170/8159810

Answer (score 0):

Here how i implement cookie handling for android lollipop - tiramisu and also jvm and non-persistent connection.

requires:

```ini
[versions]
webkit = "1.10.0"
okhttp = "4.12.0"

[libraries]
webkit = { module = "androidx.webkit:webkit", version.ref = "webkit" }
okhttp = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom", version.ref = "okhttp" }
okhttp-lib = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp" }
```

```
implementation libs.webkit
implementation platform(libs.okhttp)
implementation libs.okhttp.lib
```

create `WebkitCookieManager.kt`

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.webkit.WebView
import okhttp3.Cookie
import okhttp3.CookieJar
import okhttp3.HttpUrl
import java.net.CookieHandler
import java.net.CookiePolicy
import java.net.HttpCookie


/**
 * android webkit webview cookie manager.
 * [FULL USAGES](https://dimaslanjaka.github.io/2024/03/okhttp-cookie-handling-on-android.html)
 *
 * @author Dimas Lanjaka <a href="https://www.webmanajemen.com">https://www.webmanajemen.com</a>
 */
open class WebkitCookieManager : CookieJar {
    /**
     * support for below android 10
     */
    private var webkitCookieManager: android.webkit.CookieManager? = null

    /**
     * support for jvm or android 10+
     */
    private var javaCookieManager: java.net.CookieManager? = null

    /**
     * support for webview intercept connection cookie handling
     */
    private var webview: WebView? = null

    /**
     * the android context for clearing cookies on non-webview instance
     */
    private var context: Context? = null

    /**
     * for non-persistent cookies
     */
    private val cookieStore = mutableMapOf<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>>()

    /**
     * construct android cookie manager without webview
     */
    constructor(manager: android.webkit.CookieManager, ctx: Context? = null) {
        webkitCookieManager = manager
        setupAndroidCookieManager()
        this.context = ctx
    }

    /**
     * construct android cookie manager with webview
     */
    constructor(manager: android.webkit.CookieManager, webView: WebView, ctx: Context? = null) {
        webkitCookieManager = manager
        setupAndroidCookieManager(webView)
        this.webview = webView
        this.context = ctx
    }

    /**
     * construct non-persistent cookie manager
     */
    constructor(ctx: Context? = null) {
        this.context = ctx
    }

    /**
     * construct java cookie manager
     */
    constructor(manager: java.net.CookieManager, ctx: Context? = null) {
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)
        javaCookieManager = manager
        CookieHandler.setDefault(javaCookieManager)
        this.context = ctx
    }

    /**
     * make android webkit cookie manager accept third-party cookies
     */
    private fun setupAndroidCookieManager(webView: WebView? = null) {
        webkitCookieManager?.setAcceptCookie(true);
        if (webView != null) webkitCookieManager?.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    }

    /**
     * save cookies after request finished
     */
    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        cookies.forEach { cookie ->
            webkitCookieManager?.setCookie(url.toString(), cookie.toString())
            javaCookieManager?.cookieStore?.add(url.toUri(), HttpCookie.parse(cookie.toString())[0])
        }
        cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
    }

    /**
     * load cookies before okhttp execute request {@link okhttp3.OkHttpClient#newCall(request)}
     */
    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        return if (webkitCookieManager != null) {
            // get from android webkit cookie manager
            when (val cookies = webkitCookieManager?.getCookie(url.toString())) {
                null -> emptyList()
                else -> cookies.split("; ").mapNotNull { Cookie.parse(url, it) }
            }
        } else if (javaCookieManager != null) {
            // get from java cookie manager
            when (val cookies = javaCookieManager?.cookieStore?.cookies) {
                null -> emptyList()
                else -> cookies.toString().split("; ").mapNotNull { Cookie.parse(url, it) }
            }
        } else {
            // get from non-persisten cookie store
            val cookies = cookieStore[url]
            return cookies ?: ArrayList()
        }
    }

    /**
     * clear all stored cookies everywhere
     */
    fun clearCookies() {
        // remove non-persistent stored cookies
        cookieStore.clear()
        // initialize android webkit cookie manager on null
        if (webkitCookieManager == null) {
            webkitCookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance()
            setupAndroidCookieManager()
        }
        // indicator when webview not initialized
        var standaloneWebview = false
        // initalize fake webview instance
        if (webview == null && context != null) {
            // declare standalone webview
            webview = WebView(context!!)
            // treat as standalone webview
            standaloneWebview = true
        }
        // remove all stored cookies from android webkit cookie manager
        webkitCookieManager?.removeAllCookies(null)
        webkitCookieManager?.flush()
        webkitCookieManager?.removeSessionCookies(null);
        // clear all caches from webview
        webview?.clearCache(true)
        webview?.clearHistory()
        webview?.clearFormData();
        webview?.clearSslPreferences();
        if (standaloneWebview) {
            // destroy standalone webview
            webview?.destroy()
            webview = null
        }
        // initialize java cookie manager
        if (javaCookieManager == null) {
            javaCookieManager = java.net.CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)
            java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(javaCookieManager)
        }
        // remove all stored cookies from java cookie manager
        javaCookieManager?.cookieStore?.removeAll()
    }
}
```

my usage within view binding webview + custom webviewclient intercept using okhttp

```kotlin
val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
clientBuilder.cookieJar(WebkitCookieManager(CookieManager.getInstance(), binding!!webview, applicationContext))
```

[image: declaration of okhttp]

[image: on intercept section create connection]

this work and tested, when i clear cookies the value of cookies on website changed, otherwise all same until expiration date of cookie.