# How to use a REST API with Sessions in Android

Tags: android, rest

I need to write a client that uses session cookies in Java for Android to use. I think I got the hang of writing Android apps, but when looking for a library to use for REST apis I only found very, very low level APIs - which is fine, but I don't understand it.

I have this in python requests, which I need to convert into Java/Android.

```
import requests;
import json;
s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Host': 'REMOVED',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1',
    'User-Agent': 'REMOVED',
}

data = '{"username":"???","language":0,"password":"???"}'

s.post('REMOVED', headers=headers, data=data)

headers = {
    'Host': 'REMOVED',
    'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1',
    'User-Agent': 'REMOVED',
}

r = s.get('REMOVED', headers=headers)
students = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
for n in students['d']['results']:
    print(n['nameOfStudent'] + ' at ' + n['nameOfSchool'])
```

If you like it better, here are my two requests in cURL form.

```
curl -H "Host: ???" -H "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1" -H "User-Agent: REMOVED" --data-binary '{"username":"???","language":0,"password":"???"}' --compressed <URL REMOVED>
```

and

```
curl -H "Host: REMOVED" -H "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Cookie: SessID=REMOVED; SessPro=REMOVED" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1" -H "REMOVED" --compressed <URL REMOVED>
```

The cookie bit is handled by python requests in my python script.

I'm trying to implement this as a login (as you could probably tell) and as such I'm using the default Android Studio login activity.

It looks like this right now, but I want it to actually login and start a session.

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Here's where I'm importing OkHttp3:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Look into the OkHttp library. Here's a link on handling cookies with that library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24267060/1478764

Comment: Will that support HTTPS though?

Comment: Yes of course it will.

Comment: I get http://i.imgur.com/1AEwJZ4.png even after just copy+pasting the example, and I can't find docs for OkHttp

Comment: @ReverseCold are you sure that you've imported OkHttp 3? Post the gradle lines where you're importing OkHttp3.

Comment: @Sufian Yes, I edited my post to show the import in gradle.

Comment: You are missing this in your gradle `compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0"`. As you can see, the `JavaNetCookieJar.java` is in `okhttp-urlconnection`. As seen [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/okhttp3).