# Okhttp3 get cookie

Tags: java, cookies, okhttp

I am doing this request :

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "username=George&password=toto");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8080/login")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But how to get the cookies that the **server returned me**? I just want to store it on a **String** variable (that's all)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to create or use an existing `CookieJar` implementation and then read the cookies from that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746219) for more details.