# Use cookies in android application

Tags: android, cookies

I'm try to implement assigning cookies to android app without using WebView.
So I have `/login` url and `/api/*` urls which are protected by authorization. 
I want send cookie after correct login and use this cookie to get protected urls from `/api/*`
How can I implement cookies in android application?

Comment: `How can I implement cookies in android application?` depends on how you make network requests. Each approach has it's own way to handle cookies

Comment: I make network request with `AndroidNetworking`. But which approaches are exist?

Comment: `which approaches are exist` there are probably 100 of them. I won't list all of them, sorry. have you tried searching to find out how to work with cookies in AndroidNetworking?

Comment: Hah... I'm trying to understand the way of solution.

But what I've heard from you @Vladislav is: 'There are many solutions,.. '

Comment: actually no, I've said that there is a solution for every way of networking. The solution depends on the way you use. You are using `AndroidNetworking`, have you tried searching for how to use cookies in AndroidNetworking?

Comment: Please check the Android Networking documentation: https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/cookie.html

Answer (score -1):

As you are not using a WebView for calling your URLs and Cookies in general is just a way of storing small pieces of data I would use SharedPreferences instead.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Here you can store key pairs of strings, ints etc and reach from anywhere within your app.

Or for cookies you could use OKHttp like this answer suggests: [How to implement cookie handling on Android using OkHttp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263921/how-to-implement-cookie-handling-on-android-using-okhttp)